# Looking to create a bot to crawl API and store data in an excel/csv file

Tags: api, screen-scraping, web-crawler, web-scraping, bots

Hey guys this question is a bit nebulous so I apologize...I'm just looking for help in sending me to the right direction.

I would like to develop some sort of bot/script/program that can crawl some API I have keys for and parse the XML into a csv or excel file so I can check it then import it into my database.

For example, I have a developer account with meetup.com.  I would like to build a bot that could crawl through their entire database of upcoming meetup events and parse the xml to given column in the excel document.

My programming experience has been limited to Ruby on Rails lately, but I wouldnt mind learning python or something else if I had to.  SO I'm really just looking for direction on where to start or some good tutorial sites, etc.

If someone's already built something that can do what I'm talking about brownies points..

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to crowl the entire website and get the informations you must learn socket development, or just depent on some already created libraries, this website contains a  lot of books talking about how to code Bots Spiders and Crawlers that I used.
the website is http://www.jeffheaton.com/

Best Regards
NiL